# Fitting full table on page in Latex

Tags: tables

In the following code I have mad a table but the table is to large for the page. I am wondering how I change the formatting of the page or table to make the table fit.

I have included a screenshot of my work[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[ J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\mu_H-\mu_{H-AVD}-\mu_{H-AND} - w     & \gamma e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
w      & bp_H \frac{I_M}{N_H} - \gamma e -\mu_H & 0 & \sigma & 0 & 0 & -bp_H \frac{S_H}{N_H} \\ 
0      & bp_H \frac{I_M}{N_H} & - \left( \mu_H + \mu_{H-YF} +  r \right) & 0 & 0 & 0 & bp_H \frac{S_H}{N_H} \\ 
0      & 0 & r  & -\mu _ H - \sigma & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0      & 0 & -bp_H \frac{S_M}{N_H}  & 0 & -bp_M \frac{I_H}{N_H} - \mu_M & \alpha_M & \alpha_M \\ 
    0      & 0 & bp_M \frac{S_M}{N_H}  & 0 & bp_M \frac{I_H}{N_H} & -\beta -\mu_M & 0 \\ 
  0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \beta & -\mu _M
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, what kind are the indices? E.g. `H-AND` is a subtraction, where the product `A` * `N` * `D` is subtracted from `H`, or it is more textual, the minus is rather a hyphen and should be typeset as `\text{H-AND}`, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[ J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A    & \gamma e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
w      & B & 0 & \sigma & 0 & 0 & -bp_H \frac{S_H}{N_H} \\ 
0      & bp_H \frac{I_M}{N_H} & C & 0 & 0 & 0 & bp_H \frac{S_H}{N_H} \\ 
0      & 0 & r  & D & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0      & 0 & -bp_H \frac{S_M}{N_H}  & 0 & E & \alpha_M & \alpha_M \\ 
    0      & 0 & bp_M \frac{S_M}{N_H}  & 0 & bp_M \frac{I_H}{N_H} & F & 0 \\ 
  0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \beta & G
\end{bmatrix}
\]
where
\begin{align*}
A&=-\mu_H-\mu_{H-AVD}-\mu_{H-AND} - w \\
B&=bp_H \frac{I_M}{N_H} - \gamma e -\mu_H\\
C&= - \left( \mu_H + \mu_{H-YF} +  r \right)\\
D&=-\mu _ H - \sigma\\
E&=-bp_M \frac{I_H}{N_H} - \mu_M\\
F&=-\beta -\mu_M\\
G&=-\mu _M
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you beat me for 11 second with the same answer as i prepare :-) +1

Comment: is there anyway to fit it all on one page though?

Comment: @user123 as one matrix? you need a bigger page or a font so small that no one can read it (latex will let you do either of those things, but do you really want to?) as above it fits on one page doesn't it?

Comment: yes I think you have done it properly, thanks again!